# rails includes for has_many through when cross referenced in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, has-many-through

```
class Foo
  # attribute amount
  has_many :foobars
  has_many :bars, through: :foobars
end

class Bar
  has_one :foobars
  has_one :foo, through: :foobar

  # this method gets automatically included in the bar object as attribute
  def amount
    self.foo.amount
  end
end

class FooBar
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :bar
end

class FoosController
  def show
     foo = base_class.find(some_id)
     respond_with foo.as_json(include: :bar)
  end

  def base_class
    Foo.includes(:foobars, :bars)
  end
end
```

Important part is the controller#base_class where I include the relations to reduce stress on the db since the `:bar` gets included in the `:foo` response. But I get sort of a n+1 issue because `:bar` also loads `foo.amount` Bullet gem suggests adding `:foo` to `Foo.includes(:foobars, :bars)` But foo does not have the relation foo and will fail obviously.

How can I include/preload/join to get this n+1 resolved?

Comment: Use a hash to include nested assocations: `Foo.includes(foobars: :bars)`. https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#nested-associations-hash

Comment: Why do not you use `delegate :amount, to: :foo` inside foo class ?

Comment: @ray Well in my rl example the naming of the attributes is different in the models. But delegate has the same issue since its just builds a getter method, right?

Comment: @DennyMueller yes, works same, just told you for more readability

Comment: Could you fix your models first, or show the real ones? Now your model name is `FooBar` which makes `has_many :foobars` association impossible, there should be `has_many :foo_bars`. Also `has_one :foobars` is incorrect - there should be `has_one :foo_bar`